# Help finding Expected Value

Tags: probability

Problem:
Suppose that $x$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on the interval $(0,6)$ and $y = (x-3)^2$. What is $E(y^2)$?
Answer:
First observe that $u_x = E(x)  = 3$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(y) &=& E((x-3)^2) = E(x^2) -6E(x) + 9 \\
E(x^2) &=& \int_0^6 \frac{x^2}{6} \,\,\, dx  = \frac{x^3}{18} \Big|_0^6  = \frac{6^3}{18}\\
E(x^2) &=& \frac{6(36)}{{18}} = \frac{36}{3} = 12 \\
E(y) &=& E((x-3)^2) = 12 - 6(3) + 9 = 12 - 18 + 9 = 3 \\
E(y^2) &=& E((x-3)^4) = E( (x^2 - 6x + 9)^2 ) \\
(x^2 - 6x + 9)^2 &=& x^4 - 6x^3 + 9x^2 - 6x^3 + 36x^2 - 54x + 9x^2 - 54x + 81  \\
(x^2 - 6x + 9)^2 &=& x^4 -12x^3 + 54x^2 -108x + 81 \\
E(y^2) &=& E( x^4 -12x^3 + 54x^2 -108x + 81 ) \\
E(x^3) &=& \int_0^6 \frac{x^3}{6} \,\,\, dx  = \frac{x^4}{24} \Big|_0^6  = \frac{6^4}{24} = \frac{6^3}{4} \\
E(x^3) &=& \frac{6(36)}{4} = 6(9) = 54 \\
E(x^4) &=& \int_0^6 \frac{x^4}{6} \,\,\, dx  = \frac{x^5}{30} \Big|_0^6 = \frac{6^5}{30} = \frac{6^4}{5} \\
E(y^2) &=& \frac{6^4}{5} - 12(54) + 54(12) - 108(3) + 81 = \frac{6^4}{5} - 324 + 81 \\
E(y^2) &=& \frac{6^4}{5} - 243 = \frac{6^4 - 243(5) }{5} \\
E(y^2) &=& \frac{81}{5} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, I will try an alternative approach as suggested by lulu.
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(y^2) &=& \int_0^6 (x-3)^4 \,\,\, dx = \frac{(x-3)^5}{5} \Big|_0^6 \\
E(y^2) &=&\frac{(6 - 3)^5}{5} - \frac{(0 - 3)^5}{5}  = \frac{3^5}{5} + \frac{3^5}{5} \\
E(y^2) &=& \frac{486}{5}
\end{eqnarray*}
However, since the two methods are producing different answers, I conclude that I made a mistake some where. I am hoping somebody here can point it out.
Thanks
Bob

Comment: Seems like a lot of work.  $E[y^2]= \frac 16\,\int_0^6 (x-3)^4\,dx$ and $\int (x-3)^4=\frac 15\,(x-3)^5$.

Comment: You forgot the $36x^2$ when expanding $(x-3)^4$ (it's $54x^2$, not $18x^2$)

Comment: check things when you take to power of $4$ ...

Comment: @lulu Woops you got there before me, feel free to post an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Furrane  Oh, thanks for the acknowledgement but leave your answer.  After all, you actually wrote up the calculation properly! (+1)

Comment: @lulu well for once I found a question that seemed easy to answer haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well $y = (x-3)^2$ so $y^2 = (x-3)^4$ hence :

$$E(y^2) =  \int_0^6 {1\over 6} (x-3)^4 dx ={1\over 6}\cdot \left| {1\over 5}(x-3)^5\right|_0^6 = {1\over 6}\cdot {1\over 5}\cdot (3^5 - (-3)^5) = {1\over 6}\cdot {1\over 5}\cdot 2\cdot 3^5 = {3^4\over 5} = {81\over 5} = 16.2$$

Comment: With help from @Furrane, I see where I went wrong. I can now fix the problem.

Comment: @Bob No problem mate, sometimes I too get into a problem so hard that I somehow lose sight of the bigger picture =)
Feel free to confirm my answer, it helps me =)

Comment: @Bob use the little tick just below the voting down arrow, it signals I answered your question.